# @sys.any gets all the string as the parameter value in api.ai

Tags: dialogflow-es

I'm working with api.ai and have a "user says" sentence like this:

Let's reserve a hotel named Flamingo with rents one night stay at 100$, two nights stay rented at 200$.

I defined "Flamingo" as hotel-name and its entity is @sys.any,"100$" as one-night and "200$" as two-nights and their entity is @sys.unit-currency.

Now, when I try this in "Try this now" section of api.ai, "hotel-name" is set to the whole sentence and "one-night" and "two-nights" are empty.

Would you please help me in this problem?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a Entity of type "Hotels" and add "Flamingo" to it.
Then you should change @sys.any to @Hotels

Answer (score 0):

& that is because `@sys.any` will take any input which is coming its way. You should define @Hotel-names entity which has these hotel names entered as Flamingo,..,...etc etc & then use it in intent. That will help.